# python beautiful soup extract href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

so I'm testing Beautiful soup with python (it's great for those how are wondering)

I have a problem when i want to get the href from a link that i got, and i don't understand why I can't get it.

here is my code:

```
for url in soup.find_all('article'):
if "Gonz Logo" in url.get_text():
    if "Black" in url.get_text():
        print(url)
```

this works but it gives me this:

```
<article><div class="inner-article"><a href="/shop/jackets/gw1diqgyr/n53istanq" style="height:150px;"><img alt="N7qmqyee 3g" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/147789/vi/N7qMqyEe_3g.jpg" width="150"/></a><h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/gw1diqgyr/n53istanq">Gonz Logo Coaches Jacket </a></h1><p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/gw1diqgyr/n53istanq">Black</a></p></div></article>
```

(yeah a big line...)

the probleme is i only want to get the href. when I try:

```
    print(url.get('href'))
```

I get in output : None

I have no idea why.

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I think you get None because of `soup.find_all('article')`. And when you do `url.get('href')` you don't get the link.

To get the link I would recommend you to get all `a` tags using regex, for eg:

```
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9_()]')})
# now iterate over the links and
for link in links:
    # get url
    url = link.get('href')
    print(url)
```

Comment: HI, i found my answer! but i still want to understand your code. what does the first line do?

Comment: It's getting all the `href` links matching the regex written. You can customize it as per your choice.

Comment: so if I use this i need to change what is under the '[a-zA-Z0-9_()]'? but if i have 2 variables like in my exemple how can it work?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
for url in soup.find_all('article'):
if "Gonz Logo" in url.get_text():
    if "Black" in url.get_text():
        for child_a in url.find_all('a'):
           print(child_a['href'])
```

Comment: got an error : 
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: basically you need to get to the `a` element inside that `article`, and then extract `href` which belongs to that `a` element.

Comment: note that the code above will give you all `href`s inside the article

Comment: ahh nice thanks! I got it. but in what i was returning i guess i was trying to get the 3 links in 1 that's why it wasn't working.
now i just need to get 1 lin and it should be all good. thank a lot

Comment: your code tries to get the `href` attribute in the variable named `url`, which stores the `article`. However, `article` has no attribute `href`. In fact, it has no attribute at all. thats why it returns `None`. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

By slighly modifying Ali Yilmaz's solution as following (href=True):

```
for url in soup.find_all('article'):
if "Gonz Logo" in url.get_text():
    if "Black" in url.get_text():
        for child_a in url.find_all('a', href=True):
           print(child_a['href'])
```

It works fine